# How can I enable remote debugging in MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, debugging

I am trying to debug a stored Procedure from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 which is connected to MS SQL Server 2008 Database Instance running on a different system.

System Information:
1. Remote system is running with Symantec End Point Security

I have done the following settings for running the remote debugger:

1. I have added the inbound Rules for  TCP 139, TCP 445, UDP 137 and UDP 138 ports.
2. My local system's instance is running with sysadmin user role.
3. I have added the sqlservr.exe and svchost.exe at server windows firewall exception list.
4. I have added the svchost.exe and ssms.exe at client windows firewall exception list.
5. The SSMS and SQL server services are running in the same domain.
6. Following necessary services are running properly

   - TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper
   - Remote Registry
   - RPC Service

But after doing all these specified steps i am getting following error after clicking the debugger button in client SSMS.

Unable to start T-SQL Debugging. Could not attach to SQL Server process on 'remotesystem_name'. Click Help for more information.

If there is another alternative please let make me aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a new login account (windows authentication account) on server for my machine.

Comment: Let me check at my end and then see the output